How can we set fieldproperty of setfflags to read-only a formfield using java itext 8.0.4 version
form.setfieldproperty(field, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);

How can we set fieldproperty of setfflags to read-only a formfield using Java iText 8.0.4 version, when migrating code from iText 5 version ?

The class PdfFormField has a method setReadOnly that sets just that flag.

PdfFormField has various flags how do we know that setfflags is only enabled with read-only if we set setReadOnly to true?

"PdfFormField has various flags how do we know that setfflags is only enabled with read-only if we set setReadOnly to true?" - Compare the code! Both iText versions in question are open source, so simply look into the sources.

Thanks for the help @mkl, checked the source code it looks fine, based on each property we have a setter

formFields.get(field).setReadOnly(true);
can be used to setfflags to read-only using java itext 8.0.4
